# После поиска кнопки не работают

Tags: javascript, html

У меня возникла одна большая. Есть список кнопок, есть их переключатели(вперёд и назад по этому списку), есть так же поле поиска, по которому можно найти нужную кнопку. При переключении кнопок на экране записывается имя текущей кнопки списка. При поиске по имени кнопки, если имя верное, то поиск выведет на экране имя кнопки, если поиск не удался, то выведет сообщение об ошибку ввода. До поиска кнопки переключения нормально работают(т.е.  при нажатии вперёд или назад на экране появляется имя текущей кнопки), они нормально работают так же после неудавшегося поиска, но возникает большая проблема после удачного поиска - кнопки переключения перестают функционировать, т.е. на экране не отображается имя кнопки, на которую переключились. Консоль браузера выдаёт ошибку.

Помогите пожалуйста, я над этой проблемой уже больше 6 часов бьюсь, но без результатов.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
    at i.js:45
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

Если кому-то нужно могу переслать js, но не думаю, что это поможет.

Comment: Нам поможет пример вашего кода. С воспроизводимой проблемой.

Comment: Мой код содержит json файл большого размера =((

Comment: А нам не нужен весь json файл. Сделайте минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Куда скинуть код?

Comment: Хорошо. Сейчас мы Вам скажем, что делать, не глядя на Ваш код.

Comment: @Igor, проблема с кодом, но я был бы согласен, если кто-то помог мне написать новый код.

Comment: Покажите хотя бы 45-ую строчку файла `i.js`.

Comment: Код скидывайте в вопрос. Можете даже создать рабочий сниппет. С js, html и css.

Comment: @Igor, Прямо здесб?

Comment: Ну, давайте мы с Вами встретимся в каком-нибудь приятном месте, и Вы покажете там.

Comment: @Igor, всё, исправил.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, всё, исправил

Comment: А код то зачем из вопроса удалили?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы удаляете элемент `p` внутри `.result` в строчке

```
result.textContent = res;
```

После этого `document.querySelector("div.result > p")` возвращает `null`.

Используйте в обоих местах

```
document.querySelector("div.result > p").textContent = ...;
```

Comment: Ок, попробую и быстро сообщу.

Comment: спасибо братаан джан, твоя помощь неоценима.